# How do I use the script provided for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, email-validation

I found an email validation script from PyPI and I installed it succesfully.

When trying to run it, nothing happeneds. I'm not sure what I missed here.
I'm trying the following in the Python terminal:

```
from validate_email import validate_email

is_valid = validate_email(email_address='example@example.com', check_regex=True, check_mx=True, from_address='my@from.addr.ess', helo_host='my.host.name', smtp_timeout=10, dns_timeout=10, use_blacklist=True, debug=False)
```

I don't get any error, but I don't get any answer, just a `>>>` back.
Ultimately I would like to get a `True`/`False` or maybe even download it to a `.txt`.

Any idea of what I am missing out?

EDIT: I added print(is_valid) as the third code and it gave me False back which was expected!

The only thing I wonder now is how to get it down to a .txt or maybe even excel?

Comment: What happens when you add `print(is_valid)`?

Comment: It prints false as expected! Thanks, that was a quick fix.

Comment: For check the domain mx and verify email exits you must have the pyDNS package installed:.`pip install pyDNS`

Comment: Any updated version on that @Salio ? PyDNS seems like its last release was 2012.

Comment: You may use external api to validate emails.

I got an example from:
https://app.mailcheck.co/assets/md/example.py


`
import requests

url = "https://api.mailcheck.co/v1/singleEmail:check"

payload = '{ "email": "email@example.com" }'
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'authorization': 'Bearer API_KEY_GOES_HERE'
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
`

Also there is ready to go csv processing availible on site.

But free quota isn't big, you will need to buy some plan to validate more than 100 email